# Add JavaFX (of JDK8) in sbt (using the play framework)

Tags: sbt, java-8, playframework-2.2, javafx-8

The goal is to have a standalone Play Framework (2.2) application having an additional status window open containing some javafx (javafx-8) elements.

Since JavaFX classes are now on the default runtime classpath for an Oracle Java 8 implementation using javafx.* in my classes and compiling with sbt should just be fine.

However sbt can't find these classes and quits with

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application]
```

when executing

```
..\path-to-play-framework-2.2\play project run
```

The best way to fix this problem seems to be the modification of build.sbt in the project directory. What can I do to add the missing (class) path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly JavaFX doesn't link that easily to an sbt build. You need to set your JAVA_HOME environment variable and do modifications to your build file.

[Here](https://github.com/Astrac/rest-life/blob/master/project/AutomataBuild.scala) I have a repository where this is set up. The important bit if you are using an sbt build rather than a scala build is this one:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile += Attributed.blank(
  file(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar")),

fork in run := true
```

The reason for this is that jfxrt.jar is the archive containing the JavaFX runtime and it is not included in the classpath of an sbt project by default.

Comment: I suggest changing the path to jfxrt.jar for JDK8. It is available at /jre/lib/ext. Is there still a way to avoid setting the JAVA_HOME env?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are using JDK8. The concept should be the same anyway, you need to locate your jfxrt.jar. The JAVA_HOME env is not mandatory but it is probably the most commonly used way to get the jre path on a system. You could try other approaches (e.g. copy the jfxrt.jar file in an appropriate folder in your project, provide the jre path by configuration or try to detect it somehow, etc), the important thing is that sbt is aware of where this jar is and that the run command forks (as it won't otherwise see changes you do to the classpath).

Comment: Even though I had to modify this code and add a fallback in case a JDK/JRE will not be found, I'll mark that as the answer because it gave me the right direction.

Comment: @AldoStracquadanio can you explain this answer a little more? I'm seeing no change at all when I add the unmanagedJars entry, and it works with just the fork enabled. Sadly, forking also breaks a bunch of things like setting properties on the cli and the debugger from Intellij.

Comment: @OwenNelson I am not sure, I didn't do any JavaFX in the last year and I don't have a project to try this on (my previous answer was based on my experience on Java 7). I read somewhere that since Java 8 you don't need to add the JavaFX jar to the classpath as it uses the extension mechanism, so that could explain why you don't need the unmanagedJars entry. It doesn't explain why you need the `fork` bit though, sorry about that.

Comment: @AldoStracquadanio thanks. After messing around a couple days, it looks like this may be localized to specific jdk update versions. Adding the jar to `unmanagedJars`, without the fork, is working for me on jdk 8u60 but did not work on 8u40. Switching to u60 came with it's own quirks however. Still, my issue was solved!

Comment: I'm on 8u51 and can confirm I'm still getting the same problem. I'll update to the newest version of java 8 to see if that makes the difference.

Comment: It's working for me now after I updated to 8u65. But it didn't work right after I updated. I'm running the application from within IntelliJ, so I had to make sure the IDE had access to `System.env("JAVA_HOME")` which it originally did not. For my use case, I needed to add that environment variable to /env/environment so it would be available to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Anotherway is to set the Classpath for sbt. This can be done on the machines which can't resolve JavaFX.

```
SBT_OPTS="-Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/share/java/openjfx/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar"
```